# VS CODE - PHP CS FIXER, replace double quotes with single ones on auto format?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I've looked up many sites, forums and such, but couldn't find a working answer. My goal is to replace `"` with `'`, when I format the php documents. I mostly found stuff for `prettier`, but I'm not using prettier - I'm using PHP CS FIXER.

Example:

Before save:

```php
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return redirect("here")->intended("dashboard")->with('success', 'Signed in');
}
```

After save:

```php
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    return redirect('here')->intended('dashboard')->with('success', 'Signed in');
}
```

Comment: You'll need to set up a rule in your PHP CS Fixer configuration, you'll want to include the single_quote rule, which ensures that simple strings use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: I've tried looking for it in the >settings, and also tried to add it to the settings json, but it ignores every form of single_quote. For example, I tried `"php-cs-fixer.singleQuote": true,`, `"php-cs-fixer.single_quote": true,`, and some other combinations I can't recall so quickly. I also swept through the settings as-is, but I couldn't find any options about single quotes, or quotes in general.

Comment: I also tried adding `quote_type = single` to .editorconfig, but that did nothing either.

Comment: Create or edit your .php-cs-fixer.php or .php_cs.dist file. This file should be in the root of your project directory. If it doesn't exist, you'll need to create it.
Set up your rules. You'll want to include the single_quote rule, which ensures that simple strings use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Do you have a config file which contains the settings (.php-cs-fixer.php) (look in settings - PHP-cs-fixer: Config)